# Make Operator WITH from oracle work in hsql database

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a native query that needs to run in HSQL(for in-memory tests) and in Oracle DB (for production), however, the query keyword "RECURSIVE" is required in HSQL database and it is not allowed in oracle. Since i need that both statements run on both engines, there is some common similiar operator?

The oracle query is:

```
WITH contexts (ID, CONTEXT_ID, NAME, LABEL_KEY, VERSION, parent_name, parent_id, lev) 
AS (
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.CONTEXT_ID, t1.NAME, LABEL_KEY, VERSION, NULL AS parent_name, NULL AS parent_id, 1 AS lev
  FROM PIM_CONTEXT t1 WHERE t1.ID =1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT t2.ID, t2.CONTEXT_ID, t2.NAME, t2.LABEL_KEY, t2.VERSION, contexts.NAME AS parent_name, contexts.ID AS parent_id, lev + 1 AS lev 
  FROM contexts 
  JOIN PIM_CONTEXT t2 ON t2.context_id = contexts.id 
) 
SELECT ID, CONTEXT_ID, NAME, LABEL_KEY, VERSION, parent_name, parent_id FROM contexts;
```

and the query that has the same output in HSQL is:

```
WITH contexts recursive (ID, CONTEXT_ID, NAME, LABEL_KEY, VERSION, parent_name, parent_id, lev) 
AS (
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.CONTEXT_ID, t1.NAME, LABEL_KEY, VERSION, NULL AS parent_name, NULL AS parent_id, 1 AS lev
  FROM PIM_CONTEXT t1 WHERE t1.ID =1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT t2.ID, t2.CONTEXT_ID, t2.NAME, t2.LABEL_KEY, t2.VERSION, contexts.NAME AS parent_name, contexts.ID AS parent_id, lev + 1 AS lev 
  FROM contexts 
  JOIN PIM_CONTEXT t2 ON t2.context_id = contexts.id 
) 
SELECT ID, CONTEXT_ID, NAME, LABEL_KEY, VERSION, parent_name, parent_id FROM contexts;
```

I need some alternative that can run over both engines.

Comment: Upgrade to Oracle 12c, which supports recursive CTEs.

Comment: We already have Oracle 12c and CTEs, the problem is only the "Recursive" keyword required by the H2SQL database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff recursive CTEs are supported in Oracle 11g as well.

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit with the query and perhaps some sample data?

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk Done.

Comment: I don't think there's a common expression that will work in both databases. Maybe create a view in each db with your queries (if that's possible), then your application just has to query the view.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk I can't do it in HSQL. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest HSQLDB code (post 2.3.4) supports this in the Oracle syntax compatibility mode. A snapshot jar is available from Maven repositories.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks @fredt, i will update when they release a final version, i can't use SNAPSHOT.